# Timestamp not injected when the coulmn is "protected range"

Tags: google-sheets

I've made a sheet with two different timestamp events for Coulmn A and B.

These works great, but I want to protect these two coulmns so the users can't delete the timestamp values. 
If I set a protect range rule, the script will not inject timestamps into coulmn a and b for the users.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onEdit` trigger runs anonymously. It cannot determine the current user.

You may try using an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. If that person will have an access to protected ranges, the timestamp will work.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!

Comment: Used the information from the page and it worked like a charm,thanks!